# Evaluate the integral of $\frac{2-3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral of $\frac{2-3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

I've got 
$$\int\frac{2}{1-x^2} - ∫\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$2∫\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - 3∫\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$2\sin^{-1}(x) - ???$$

How would I integrated $3∫\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$?

Comment: "Solve" should be written "evaluate"...

Comment: Did you consider a substitution $y=x^2$?

Comment: @ComputerSage1337 The first line is wrong, it should be $$\int\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x - \int\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I am somewhat surprised seeing the number of downvotes on this question. Posts where the OP show their attempt are usually well-received.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, given $$\int \frac{2-3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\int \frac{\frac{4}{3}-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$
$$=2\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx+\frac{3}{2}\int \frac{(-2x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$ now, let $x=\sin \theta \implies dx=\cos\theta d\theta$ 
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}\cos \theta d\theta=\int  d\theta=\theta =\sin^{-1}(x)$$
Now, let $1-x^2=t\implies -2xdx=dt$ $$\int \frac{(-2x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx=\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=2\sqrt t=2\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Hence, we get 
$$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{\int \frac{2-3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx=2\sin^{-1}(x)+3\sqrt{1-x^2}+C}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
Let $u=1-x^2$ then $du=-2xdx$ so
$$\frac{-1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du=\frac{-1}{2}2\sqrt{u}+C=-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$